# Correct ways of using boring

Tags: nouns

I know that bored is used to describe how we feel, like I was bored at home. But is it correct to say: It is boring at the pond?

Answer (score 2):

It can be, but the meaning is subtly different. "Bored" as you said, as a way that a person can feel. "Boring" is a condition or state of things which causes a person to be bored.

> I was bored at home.

Simply describes how the speaker felt.

> It is boring at my home.

Says that things **are** boring there, and that anyone would or might feel bored there. It at least pretends to a greater degree of objectivity.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score -1):

Typically, *boring* is an adjective applied to a noun directly. Instead of saying

> It is boring at the pond

a native speaker is likely to say

> The pond is boring

By extension, people can be boring.

> Don't invite Fred. He's boring.

Even great works of art, like opera and great literature, can be not to everyone's taste and so fall into this category:

> You like opera? Dude, that's so boring!